# MySQL Prepared Statement - How to Loop Through

Tags: mysql, sql, prepared-statement

I have a table filled with ID numbers, which I need to loop through, and use as variables in a prepared statement.  I do not know if I need to use a stored procedure for this, or if a regular query can do it.  Here is a simple example.

```
SELECT id from var_list;

loop through @ID = var_list.id ....


SET @s1 = "SELECT * FROM data WHERE id = @ID"; 
PREPARE stmt1 FROM @s1;
EXECUTE stmt1;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;
```

As mentioned in the comment, I just need this to export some data, I have about 50-100 ID's in the table and have a query written to export a file to server for a single one at a time.

EDIT
I plan to dump the results of each iteration into a file using something like ....

```
INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/orders.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish?  In general, try to stay away from the `looping` concept, as cursors are extremely slow.  If you're returning the results from your data table that are in your var_list table, use a `JOIN` instead.

Comment: I need to export a series of CSV reports, I have the query written for each individual ID, but I have about 50 to loop through.

Comment: I need to loop around the prepared statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have already suggested, we typically *avoid* looping through a resultset **RBAR** (row by agonizing row) primarily for performance reasons. We just don't want to get into the habit of looping through a resultset. But that doesn't answer the question you asked.

To answer the question you asked, here's a rudimentary example of a MySQL stored program that uses a CURSOR to individually process rows returned by a query.  MySQL doesn't support anonymous blocks, so the only way to do this is in a MySQL stored program, like a PROCEDURE

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE loop_through_var_list
BEGIN
   DECLARE done INT DEFAULT 0;
   DECLARE v_id INT DEFAULT NULL;  
   DECLARE csr_var_list CURSOR FOR SELECT id FROM var_list ORDER BY id;
   DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = 1;
   OPEN csr_var_list;
   get_id: LOOP
      FETCH csr_var_list INTO v_id; 
      IF done = 1 THEN
         LEAVE get_id;
      END IF;

      -- at this point, we have an id value in v_id, so we can do whatever
      SET @s1 = CONCAT('SELECT ... WHERE id =''', v_id, ''' ...');


   END LOOP get_id;
   CLOSE csr_var_list;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

To execute the procedure:

```
CALL loop_through_var_list();
```

NOTES: The syntax for processing a CURSOR in MySQL is quite a bit different than other databases.

To get the "looping", we need to use a `LOOP ... END LOOP` construct.

But to prevent that loop from running forever, we need a LEAVE statement that will allow us to exit the loop.

We use a conditional test to determine when to leave. In this example, we want to exit after we've finished processing the last row.

The `FETCH` is going to throw an exception when there are no more rows to be fetched.

We "catch" that exception in a CONTINUE HANDLER (for some arcane reason, the "handlers" have to the last things declared; MySQL throws an error if we try to declare something after a HANDLER (other than another HANDLER.)

When MySQL throws the "no more rows" exception, that fires the handler code. In this example, we're just setting a variable (named `done`) to a value.

Since it's a "continue" handler, processing starts back up at the statement where the exception was thrown, in this case, that will be the statement following the FETCH. So, the first thing we do is check if we're "done" or not. If we're "done", then we exit the loop, and close the cursor.

Otherwise, we know that we've got an `id` value from `var_list` stored in a procedure variable named `v_id`. So now we can do whatever we want. Looks like you want to put some SQL text into a user-defined variable (including in the value of v_id into the SQL text, then PREPARE, EXECUTE, and DEALLOCATE PREPARE.

Be sure to declare the `v_id` variable with the appropriate datatype, that matches the datatype of the `id` column in `var_list`, I've just assumed that it's an INT.

When we reach the end of the loop, MySQL "loops" back to the beginning of the loop, and off we go again.

In the body of the loop, likely you'll want to CONCAT v_id into the SQL text you want to execute. Looks like you already have a handle on the PREPARE, DEALLOCATE prepare. For testing, you may want to add a LIMIT clause on the SELECT in the cursor declaration, and then do a simple SELECT v_id; in the body, just to verify the loop is working, before you add more code.

---

**FOLLOWUP**

I wanted to mention another alternative approach to the task, i.e. running a series of statements based on a template, substituting in values provided from a single SQL select statement...

For example, if I had this template:

```
SELECT * 
  INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/orders_@ID.csv'
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"'
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
FROM data 
WHERE id = @ID
ORDER BY 1
```

and I needed to replace the occurrences of @ID with a specific id value from a list returned from a SELECT statement, e.g.

```
SELECT id
  FROM var_list
 WHERE id IS NOT NULL
 GROUP BY id
```

I probably would not use a MySQL stored program with a CURSOR loop, I'd use a different approach.

I'd make use of a SELECT statement to generate a set of SQL statements which could be executed. Assuming `id` is integer type, I would likely do something like this:

```
SELECT CONCAT(' SELECT * 
                   INTO OUTFILE ''/tmp/orders_',s.id,'.csv''
                   FIELDS TERMINATED BY '','' ENCLOSED BY ''"''
                   LINES TERMINATED BY ''\n''
                FROM data
               WHERE id = ',s.id,'
               ORDER BY 1;') AS `stmt`
 FROM ( SELECT v.id
          FROM var_list v
         WHERE v.id IS NOT NULL
         GROUP BY v.id
      ) s
ORDER BY s.id
```

For every value of `id` returned from `s`, the statement returns the text of a SQL SELECT statement that could (and need to) execute. Capturing that into a text file would give me a SQL script I could run.

Comment: Thanks very much, you are a wealth of knowledge!

Comment: @JasonB: I'm not sure I emphasized this point: the example procedure I provided is _not_ tested; it's just a demonstration of the typical framework. I strongly recommend you test that, without any "real" work in the body of the procedure (maybe just add a `SELECT CONCAT('got v_id=',v_id) AS msg;` in the body of the loop, as a way to get some output, to see that the cursor loop is working.)

Comment: Understood, it is pointing me in the right direction, and that is what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

Use a simple query like:

```
SELECT *
FROM data
WHERE id IN (
    SELECT id
    FROM var_list
)
```