# Process database data to new table

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, database, sql-server-ce

I am quite new to programming but i am writing a little software to collect, store and process data.

I have data showing time taken by persons to commute as in figure A, (this is an SQL CE database (Compact Edition, No Pivoting allowed), i am using C# and WPF to program). I want to be able to convert data in table A to the form in table B, where multiple entries are sorted into single lines by date assigning the time spent by each person to his column on the corresponding row date and sums the total commute hours at the end.

I have literally gotten stuck here wondering how to do this.
I have already gotten the app to collect and store this data as in table A, I want to generate Table B:

[image]

Comment: do u have separate table for staff?

Comment: Read about pivoting.

Comment: @DevT Yes I have a seperate table for staff

Comment: @philipxy I am using SQL Compact Edition which does not allow pivoting

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear from your question whether you are trying to create a table in memory (i.e. in the program) or in SQL. As you asked to "convert data ... to form", I understand that you are trying to create an SQL table with the new form.

The problem with your requirement is that you want to create a row (record) that contains a column for each person. In order to do that, you'd have to take each row, check whether the column for that person already exists, and if not, create that column (using the ALTER command). Though this is possible, this is not the normal way of using SQL tables.

The normal way is to leave Table A as is, and read it sorted by "staff" (SELECT  * FROM tableA ORDER BY date, Staff) and calculate the result accordingly. Note - you should have an index defined on the "Staff" column. Doing it this way does not require altering the table format, but requires writing a program to generate the "report".

Comment: i want to create the table in memory. (I have a table of staff in the database)

Comment: @SilverSurfer Why do you want this table format? If it isn't for output to a human after all other query subexpressions, it is unlikely that it is a good idea. This answer explains some difficulties in generating it and that it is not usually done, but maybe it doesn't make clear that (other than for display to a person) it's just making your life more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

It seems a [MySQL View](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-view.html) will not be able to utilize a prepared statement or a stored procedure.

## Build query string Approach

You might could use two queries where one provides the list of staff and the second provides the generated-on-the-fly table B.

#### Get your staff list:

```
SELECT staff FROM A GROUP BY staff
```

#### Make string

Then loop through each staff member and generate this string for each staff:

```
(SELECT sum(A2.time) FROM A as A2 WHERE date=A1.date AND staff="<staff>") AS <staff>,
```

#### Query

Then having generated this string use it in this query:

```
SELECT A1.date,
    <insert-generated-query-string-of-staff>
    sum(time)
FROM A as A1 GROUP BY date;
```

Which could look like this generated:

```
SELECT A1.date,
    (SELECT SUM(A2.time) FROM A as A2 WHERE date=A1.date AND staff="John") AS John,
    (SELECT SUM(A2.time) FROM A as A2 WHERE date=A1.date AND staff="Jeff") AS Jeff,
    (SELECT SUM(A2.time) FROM A as A2 WHERE date=A1.date AND staff="James") AS James,
    SUM(A1.time)
FROM A as A1 GROUP BY date;
```

## Prepared Statement Approach

Similar to the previous approach except you're building the query strings through MySQL instead of your program. These will need to be executed every time you want to generate the table data.

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT CONCAT(
    "(SELECT SUM(A2.time) FROM A as A2 WHERE date=A1.date AND staff=\"",
    staff,
    "\") AS ", 
    staff
) ) INTO @staff from A;

SET @table_b = CONCAT(
    'SELECT A1.date, ',
    @staff, 
    ', SUM(A1.time) FROM A as A1 GROUP BY date'
);

PREPARE tableB from @table_b;
EXECUTE tableB;
```

## Stored Procedure Approach

I came across some other ideas mostly with examples of prepared statements 
and/or stored procedures and came up with this procedure.

I think this one is better because you don't have to re-create query like 
prepared statements.

#### To make the procedure:

```
DROP PROCEDURE generate_table_B;
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE generate_table_B()
BEGIN
    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE staff_name VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT NULL;
    DECLARE staff_list CURSOR FOR SELECT staff FROM A GROUP BY staff;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = 1;
    OPEN staff_list;
    SET @staff_stmts = '';
    get_id: LOOP
        FETCH staff_list INTO staff_name;
        IF done = 1 THEN
            LEAVE get_id;
        END IF;
        SET @staff_stmts = CONCAT(@staff_stmts, ' (SELECT SUM(A2.time) FROM A as A2 WHERE date=A1.date AND staff="', staff_name,'") AS ', staff_name,',');
    END LOOP get_id;
    CLOSE staff_list;
    SET @table = CONCAT('SELECT A1.date, ', @staff_stmts, ' SUM(A1.time) FROM A as A1 GROUP BY date');
    -- verifying the @table string generated
    -- select @table;
    PREPARE stmt FROM @table;
    -- run @table
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END //

DELIMITER ;
```

#### The statement to call in the program/script:

```
call generate_table_B();
```

## Aliases

These are specified right after a column name, calculation, query, or table.
It is optional to use `AS` after one of these.

The reason is because of the nested queries. In this case if we did not use 
aliases the inner query would be making comparisons from its query with data
from the outside query. Depending on the situation this may be the desired
result. However, our query below shows it is not what we want.

```
> SELECT date,
    ->     (SELECT SUM(time) FROM A WHERE date=date AND staff="John") AS John,
    ->     (SELECT SUM(time) FROM A WHERE date=date AND staff="Jeff") AS Jeff,
    ->     (SELECT SUM(time) FROM A WHERE date=date AND staff="James") AS James,
    ->     SUM(time)
    -> FROM A GROUP BY date;
+------+------+------+-------+-----------+
| date | John | Jeff | James | SUM(time) |
+------+------+------+-------+-----------+
|    1 |    9 |    8 |     4 |        10 |
|    2 |    9 |    8 |     4 |        11 |
+------+------+------+-------+-----------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Now you may notice there's the column `SUM(time)`. This qualifies as a 
calculation so we can set an alias for this column so it's friendlier to use
when selecting it. Like this:

```
>  SELECT date,
    ->      (SELECT SUM(time) FROM A WHERE date=date AND staff="John") AS John,
    ->      (SELECT SUM(time) FROM A WHERE date=date AND staff="Jeff") AS Jeff,
    ->      (SELECT SUM(time) FROM A WHERE date=date AND staff="James") AS James,
    ->      SUM(time) SummedTime
    ->  FROM A GROUP BY date;
+------+------+------+-------+------------+
| date | John | Jeff | James | SummedTime |
+------+------+------+-------+------------+
|    1 |    9 |    8 |     4 |         10 |
|    2 |    9 |    8 |     4 |         11 |
+------+------+------+-------+------------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

## Output from all 3 approaches:

```
+------+-------+------+------+--------------+
| date | James | jeff | john | SUM(A1.time) |
+------+-------+------+------+--------------+
|    1 |     2 |    3 |    5 |           10 |
|    2 |     2 |    5 |    4 |           11 |
+------+-------+------+------+--------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

## MySQL table & data:

```
> show create table A\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: A
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `A` (
  `date` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `staff` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tp` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `time` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

> SELECT * FROM A;
+------+-------+-------+------+
| date | staff | tp    | time |
+------+-------+-------+------+
|    1 | john  | bus   |    3 |
|    1 | jeff  | car   |    3 |
|    1 | James | Train |    2 |
|    2 | Jeff  | bus   |    5 |
|    2 | john  | car   |    4 |
|    2 | james | train |    2 |
|    1 | john  | train |    2 |
+------+-------+-------+------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

## sources:

- [MySQL Join Multiple Rows as Columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15462753/mysql-join-multiple-rows-as-columns)
- [MySQL Prepared Statement - How to Loop Through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25778922/mysql-prepared-statement-how-to-loop-through)
- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html
- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cursors.html

Comment: Please explain how to produce A1 and A2, i want to use the Build query string Approach. i am accessing an sqlce database, can you show me how to build this code? is it in one query?

Comment: It took me a while to explain why I used aliases. Initially I thought they might  not be necessary then I tried the query (you'll see the updated answer with it) and realized it really is necessary.

Comment: Thanks a lot @qumonio, now i understand what the code does, but i am in a little dilemma, i want to get a loop/code that  dynamically produces the query for each of these unique members as a batch query like you showed depending on database contents. This is because the user adds the staff and time in the database so i want to be able to generate the code dynamically and send it as a query. Happy New Year.

Comment: Well if you're on windows maybe a scheduled task can help or cronjob for *nix systems? I'm sorry I just realized you're not using MySQL. I tried searching to see if SQL CE has event creation abilities and I'm just not certain about what I found. Happy New Year as well.