# Clean multiple numbered mysql tables

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, phpmyadmin, cron

I have to update several tables to clean stacked cron jobs on a wordpress multisite install.

The network has 500+ plus sites and tables in wordpress are numbered so you will have:

```
wp_options
wp_1_options // for blog id 1
wp_2_options
wp_3_options
// and so on...
```

I was wondering if there is any wildcard I could use to replace that blog id number so it will take all the tables from 1 to x number at once. I tried with `wp_*_options` without any possitive result. (I'm not use to work with the DBs directly).

The query I'll be executing looks like this:

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = '' WHERE option_name = 'cron';
```

Thanks.

Comment: Now you are finding out why using metadata to separate a "big" table into smaller ones is a SQL anti pattern which you should not use.

Comment: That is not what I did, is what Wordpress does @RaymondNijland

Comment: *"That is not what I did, is what Wordpress does"* fair enough now you know Wordpress does it wrong

Comment: Why so much hate man? Also you voted negative when my question is valid @RaymondNijland

Comment: *"Also you voted negative when my question is valid"* i didn't downvote also there is no way for you to tell. *"Why so much hate man? "* i just don't like Wordpress coding/engine/solutions this is one off the reasons it isn't something personal.. *"I was wondering if there is any wildcard I could use to replace that blog id number so it will take all the tables from 1 to x number at once."* No you will have to write 500+ plus separated`UPDATE` queries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you are looking for dynamic SQL: this means using SQL to generate and execute SQL.

In MySQL, the standard approach requires creating a procedure that uses a cursor to loop through the table names and generate the queries, then use [prepared statements](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html) to execute them. This can be tricky.

For a one-shot action, I would go for an intermediate option : use a SQL query to generate a list of SQL statements. We can query against [INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-schema.html) to list the tables to update.

```
SELECT CONCAT(
    'UPDATE ', table_name, 
    ' SET option_value = NULL',
    ' WHERE option_name = ''cron'';'
) as sql_query
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_name LIKE 'wp_%_options'
```

Then, all that is left to do is manually copy the results of the query to your preferred MySQL client, and execute the whole thing as a script.

NB1: carefully check the results and tests the queries before doing this in your Production database !

NB2: the accepted answer of [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25778922/mysql-prepared-statement-how-to-loop-through) explains thoroughly the logic of both approaches, especially the stored procedure solution.